How do I make a transition from gameplay to a battle scene in unreal engine 5?
So I have recently started learning unreal engine 5 because of an idea for a 2D top down rpg based around a single fighting mechanic.
It requires me to fight in first person, but the entire game was made in a top down format and I don’t know how to make the game transition like a pokemon encounter where the main game essentially is put on pause when an enemy collides with the player character, and they are both transferred to a battle scene.
I don’t know how to word this other than a pokeman encounter type thing, and there isn’t any tutorial on YouTube to help.
I’m pretty new, started like three days ago, so all I’ve done is basically make a simple top down and the beginnings of a UI but I have yet to implement anything else because I have no idea what I’m doing or what I can even do. I can’t program worth a damn so I’ve only been playing with the Visual Scripts.

Unless you got code to work with, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ might be better place for this
